# Reactive-banana: up-to-date values from fromPoll

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

I'm writing a music player in Haskell with reactive-banana. One problem I have is fetching up-to-date values with fromPoll. I want to enable the user to optionally select a part of the track **while playing**. My code looks something like this:

```
makePlayNetworkDescr :: Player a => AddHandler Command -> a -> NetworkDescription t ()
makePlayNetworkDescr addCmdEvent player = do
    bPosition <- fromPoll (getPosition player)
    eCmds <- fromAddHandler addCmdEvent

    let eSetStart = filterE (isJust) $ bPosition <@ filterE (==SetStart) eCmds
        eSetEnd = filterE (isJust) $ bPosition <@ filterE (==SetEnd) eCmds
        eClearRange = filterE (==ClearRange) eCmds

        bStart = accumB Nothing ((const <$> eSetStart) `union` (const Nothing <$ eClearRange))
        bEnd = accumB Nothing ((const <$> eSetEnd) `union` (const Nothing <$ eClearRange))
```

Above, *getPosition* is a partial function, returning *Nothing* before the playback actually starts. The problem is that once the *addCmdEvent* fires for the first time, *bPosition* will still hold a *Nothing* value. *eSetStart/End* calculate their values based on this. Only then does *bPosition* get updated, and this is the value which will be used next time that *addCmdEvent* fires. And so on, the value will always be "off by one", so to speak.

There is a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618069/reactive-banana-firing-event-that-contain-the-most-up-to-date-value-of-a-behavi), but in that case there exists a "trigger" event which can be used to calculate the new value of the behavior. Is anything like that possible with fromPoll?

Comment: When you're finished, you should put the result on Hackage. Looking forward to playing my music from Haskell!

Comment: I do plan to put it on Hackage once (hah) I'm finished. However it's a "scratch my own itch" kind of music player to aid with transcribing music, so I'm not sure how interesting would it be to other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of reactive-banana-0.5 and 0.6, the `fromPoll` function updates the behavior whenever an external event triggers the event network. You can access these updates as an event by using

```
eUpdate <- changes bSomeBehavior
```

However, note that behaviors represent continuous time-varying values which do not support a general notion of an "update event". The `changes` function will try to return a useful approximation, but there are no formal guarantees.

Alternatively, you can change the external event to include the player position as part of the `addCmdEvent`. In your case, this means to add more data to the `SetStart` and `SetEnd` constructors. Then, you can use

```
eSetStart = filterJust $ matchSetStart <$> eCmds
    where
    matchSetStart (SetStart pos) = Just pos
    matchSetStart _              = Nothing
```

---

Both solutions require you to observe the most recent value as an event instead of a behavior. The reason is that behaviors created with `stepper` will always return the old value at the moment they are updated (they "lag behind by one"), as this is very useful for recursive definitions.

In any case, the **underlying issue** is that the player position is updated externally long before the `addCmdEvent` occurs, but the problem is that this is not what the event network sees. Rather, the network thinks that the behavior returned by `fromPoll` updates simultaneously with the `addCmdEvent`. In fact, unless you have access to the external event source that is responsible for updating the player position, that's the only thing it can think. (If you do have access, you can use the `fromChanges` function.)

I realize that this behavior of `fromPoll` is somewhat unsatisfactory for your common use case. I am undecided whether I should fix it in my library, though: there is a trade-off between `fromPoll` returning the lastest value and the `changes` function trying to do its best. If the latest value is returned, then the `changes` will behave as if it has skipped one update (when the value was updated externally) and triggered a superfluous one (when the network updates the value to match the external one). If you have any opinion on this, please let me know.

---

Note that combining behaviors with the applicative operator `<*>` will combine the most recent values just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the end I went the route of polling the position data externally and including it in the Event. Thinking about it some more, I can't really decide whether there are any conceptual benefits from getting the fresh value from fromPoll as compared to getting it from an external source, nor the other way round. On the other hand, I don't quite get the problem of fromPoll "blocking" until the fresh value is read, and only then firing the event which has actually triggered this evaluation (simultaneously with the changes event), but you know your library much better than me